# How to set Bundle in RestrictionsManager?

Tags: android

In one of the classes there is a call to extract applications restrictions bundle

```
restrictionsManager.applicationRestrictions.getString(MY_KEY)
```

But is there a way to set applications restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for RestrictionsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager) provides a helpful link to [DevicePolicyManager#setApplicationRestrictions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setApplicationRestrictions(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)), which is the other end of this API. It is used for device administration and cannot be called by normal apps.